# Diagonalize a symmetric matrix in Maxima

Tags: matrix, maxima

Here is my problem, I have a real symmetric matrix *M* depending on two parameters *a,b* (that are assumed to be positive) and I want to find an orthogonal matrix *P* such that *PMP^{-1}* is a diagonal matrix. Here is an example of what I've done :

```
assume(a>0,b>0);
M : matrix([a,a+b,a+b],[a+b,a,a+b],[a+b,a+b,a]);
load("eigen");
[myeigval,myeigvec]:similaritytransform(ev(M,hermitianmatrix));
```

or simply,

```
assume(a>0,b>0);
M : matrix([a,a+b,a+b],[a+b,a,a+b],[a+b,a+b,a]);
load("eigen");
[myeigval,myeigvec]:similaritytransform(M);
```

I get the same result for this two tests :

```
[[[2*b+3*a,-b],[1,2]],[[[1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3)]],[[1/sqrt(2),0,-1/sqrt(2)],[0,1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2)]]]]
```

The norm of the vectors is equal to 1 but this vectors do not give me an orthogonal matrix. Can somebody explain to me what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the global variables `rightmatrix` and `leftmatrix` after you call `similaritytransform`. When I try your example, I find that `rightmatrix . leftmatrix` is the identity matrix (and so is `leftmatrix . rightmatrix`).

I agree the documentation for `similaritytransform` isn't entirely clear. Oh well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that we get rightmatrix.leftmatrix = Identity but the rightmatrix is not the transpose of the leftmatrix and this is what I want. Do you know how to get that ?

Comment: @user37238 OK, I understand the question now. It appears that when some eigenvalue has multiplicity > 1, the corresponding eigenvectors returned by `similaritytransform` are not necessarily orthogonal. (That's probably a bug in `similaritytransform`.) You can apply the `gramschmidt` function to construct orthogonal vectors, although if you want orthonormal, you'll have to normalize them after `gramschmidt`.

Comment: @user37238 I think specifically what you want to do is `gramschmidt(transpose(rightmatrix))`.

Comment: @user37238 After looking at this for a bit, I think `similaritytransform` should ensure `rightmatrix` is orthogonal if the `hermitianmatrix` flag is enabled (since then it is advertised that transpose of `rightmatrix` is its inverse); if the flag is disabled, `rightmatrix` need not be orthogonal, as long as it is invertible.

Comment: I tried with similaritytransform(ev(M,hermitianmatrix)) and I don't get transpose(rightmatrix)=leftmatrix.

Comment: @user37238 I think you need to write `ev(similaritytransform(M), hermitianmatrix=true)`, i.e. call `similaritytransform` with `hermitianmatrix` temporarily bound to `true`. (Some flags which are recognized by `ev` are bound to `true` just by naming the flag; those are called `evflag`. But `hermitianmatrix` isn't an `evflag`.)